# Подсчет количества потомков в дереве-родословной

Tags: python, алгоритм, дерево

В генеалогическом древе у каждого человека, кроме родоначальника, есть ровно один родитель.

Для каждого элемента дерева определите число всех его потомков (не считая его самого).

**Формат ввода**
Программа получает на вход число элементов в генеалогическом древе N. Далее следует N−1 строка, задающие родителя для каждого элемента древа, кроме родоначальника. Каждая строка имеет вид имя_потомка имя_родителя.

**Формат вывода**
Выведите список всех элементов в лексикографическом порядке, для каждого элемента выводите количество всех его потомков.

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)

N = int(input())

dicter = dict()
names = set()


for _ in range(N - 1):
    child, parent = input().split()
    dicter[child] = parent
    names.add(child)
    names.add(parent)


def counting(person, dicter):
    return sum(1 + counting(child, dicter)
               for child, parent in dicter.items()
               if parent == person)


for n in sorted(names):
    print(f'{n} {counting(n, dicter)}')
```

Вот есть такой рабочий код, но, получается, что для каждого узла он каждый раз заново считает количество потомков и из-за этого слишком долго выполняется. Вроде понимаю, что нужно опускаться "в самый низ", начать считать снизу, а для родителя просто просуммировать кол-во потомков, которые будут у 2х его детей. Но не понимаю, как это реализовать.

Comment: Кстати, без толку ставить 100000 уровень рекурсии, где-то после 2000 плюс-минус всё-равно сам интерпретатор уже упадёт. Хотя были версии где и до 20000 что ли.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте дерево, в каждом узле которого хранится имя, список детей, и счётчик потомков.

Обойдите дерево postorder-ом. Когда возвращаетесь в узел, добавьте к его счётчику сумму счётчиков детей.

Если дерево может быть велико, используйте явный стек вместо рекурсии

Упрощённый пример (не ищется корень, нет сортировки вывода)

```
from collections import defaultdict

children = defaultdict(list)

def counting(node, children):
    cnt = 0
    for ch in children[node]:
        cnt += 1 + counting(ch, children)
    children[node].append(cnt)
    return cnt

tst = ["2 1", "3 1", "4 3", "5 3"]
for t in tst:
    ch, parent = t.split()
    children[parent].append(ch)

counting("1", children)

for k, v in children.items():
    print(k, v[-1])

1 4
3 2
2 0
4 0
5 0
```